# Create ipaddr-py IPv6Address from byte string

Tags: python, ip-address

I frequently need to convert a raw, byte-encoded IPv6 address into an IPv6Address object from the [ipaddr-py project](http://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/). Byte-encoded IPv6 addresses are not accepted by the initializer as shown here:

```
>>> import ipaddr   
>>> byte_ip = b'\x20\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01'
>>> ipaddr.IPAddress(byte_ip)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "ipaddr.py", line 78, in IPAddress
    address)
ValueError: ' \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01' does
 not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address
```

What is the easiest way to convert the byte-encoding to a format ipaddr-py can understand?
I'm using v. 2.1.10 of ipaddr.py.

My only workaround so far is way too long for the simple task:

```
>>> def bytes_to_ipaddr_string(c):
...     c = c.encode('hex')
...     if len(c) is not 32: raise Exception('invalid IPv6 address')
...     s = ''
...     while c is not '':
...         s = s + ':'
...         s = s + c[:4]
...         c = c[4:]
...     return s[1:]
...
>>> ipaddr.IPAddress(bytes_to_ipaddr_string(byte_ip))
IPv6Address('2000::1')
```

**EDIT:** I'm looking for a cross-platform solution. Unix-only won't do.

Anyone got a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`ipaddr_test.py`](http://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/source/browse/trunk/ipaddr_test.py):

```
[...]
# Compatibility function to cast str to bytes objects
if issubclass(ipaddr.Bytes, str):
    _cb = ipaddr.Bytes
else:
    _cb = lambda bytestr: bytes(bytestr, 'charmap')
[...]
```

Then

```
_cb('\x20\x01\x06\x58\x02\x2a\xca\xfe'
    '\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01')
```

provides you a `Bytes` object which is recognized by the module to contain a packed address.

I didn't test it, but it looks as if it is the way it is intended to be...

---

Meanwhile I tested it. The `_cb` stuff is presumably for older moule versions which didn't have a `Bytes` object. So you just can do

```
import ipaddr
b = ipaddr.Bytes('\x20\x01\x06\x58\x02\x2a\xca\xfe' '\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01')
print ipaddr.IPAddress(b)
```

which will result in

```
2001:658:22a:cafe:200::1
```

which is probably what you need.

Comment: Bingo, `ipaddr.IPAddress(ipaddr.Bytes(byte_ip))` works like a charm. I think the _cb stuff is for Python3 compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

On Unix IPv6 bin -> string conversion is simple - all you need is [`socket.inet_ntop`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.inet_pton):

```
>>> socket.inet_ntop(socket.AF_INET6, b'\x20\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01')
'2000::1'
```

Comment: Very clean solution, thanks. Unfortunately I need a cross-platform solution. At least *nix and Win32.